# uWSGI optimize option

Tags: python, optimization, assert, uwsgi

I was looking at adding some `assert` statements in my code and wanted to be able to pass an argument to uwsgi to be able to turn off evaluating those statements in production.  I can't seem to figure out how the [optimize option in uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#optimize) maps to the [-O command line value for python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O).  uWSGI's option takes an integer but has no description as to how it interprets or uses that integer other than saying "Set python optimization level".  However, the python docs never mention integers except with relation to the environment variable and only that an integer is equivalent to multiple `-O` arguments (which I can't see any description of what that does either, though I suspect it may do something like `-OO`)

So, what should I set the `optimize` value to to simply shut off assert statements and what should it be set to if I also want to remove docstrings? And is setting it to 0 (zero) the default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested it by setting it to zero and debug was still on but setting it to any number greater than zero turns debug off.

My code looks like this

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    assert(not __debug__)
    return "Hello World"
```

And my call looks like this

```
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --wsgi-file app.py -O 1
```

EDIT
I also added a doc-string to the function and this to the end of the app.py file

```
print "DOC STRING: %s" % application.__doc__
```

And tested with -O set to 1 and 2, with 1, I got a doc-string, with any value greater than 1 I got a None.